# I want the count of the documents dowloaded from a document library.

Tags: document-library, document

The OOTB Report that sharepoint reporting feature provides is not helpful as it is a one time thing. I want the custom code to get the count of the document dowload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning on auditing and you can write a custom report that queries the audit log for the data you need.  Or you can run your own report and sift through it in excel.